# Testing with React

Tags: reactjs, testing, mocha.js, chai, enzyme

I can't seem to test my files anymore.

I "npm i react react-dom react-addon-test-utils"

but even after all those installs,

it tells me i'm missing something

i even tried to install both devdep. and dep.

```
module.js:339
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'react-dom/lib/ReactTestUtils'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:337:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:287:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
    at require (module.js:385:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/Kainoa/DevLeague/kanakaHacks_Software/KanakaMusicR/kanakamusicR_A/node_modules/react-addons-test-utils/index.js:1:80)
    at Module._compile (module.js:425:26)
    at Module._extensions..js (module.js:432:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/Users/Kainoa/DevLeague/kanakaHacks_Software/KanakaMusicR/kanakamusicR_A/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:136:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
    at require (module.js:385:17)
    at /Users/Kainoa/DevLeague/kanakaHacks_Software/KanakaMusicR/kanakamusicR_A/node_modules/enzyme/build/react-compat.js:92:17
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/Kainoa/DevLeague/kanakaHacks_Software/KanakaMusicR/kanakamusicR_A/node_modules/enzyme/build/react-compat.js:146:5)
    at Module._compile (module.js:425:26)
    at Module._extensions..js (module.js:432:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/Users/Kainoa/DevLeague/kanakaHacks_Software/KanakaMusicR/kanakamusicR_A/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:136:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
    at require (module.js:385:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/Kainoa/DevLeague/kanakaHacks_Software/KanakaMusicR/kanakamusicR_A/node_modules/enzyme/build/Utils.js:29:20)
    at Module._compile (module.js:425:26)
    at Module._extensions..js (module.js:432:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/Users/Kainoa/DevLeague/kanakaHacks_Software/KanakaMusicR/kanakamusicR_A/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:136:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
    at require (module.js:385:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/Kainoa/DevLeague/kanakaHacks_Software/KanakaMusicR/kanakamusicR_A/node_modules/enzyme/build/MountedTraversal.js:32:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:425:26)
    at Module._extensions..js (module.js:432:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/Users/Kainoa/DevLeague/kanakaHacks_Software/KanakaMusicR/kanakamusicR_A/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:136:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
    at require (module.js:385:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/Kainoa/DevLeague/kanakaHacks_Software/KanakaMusicR/kanakamusicR_A/node_modules/enzyme/build/ReactWrapper.js:23:25)
    at Module._compile (module.js:425:26)
    at Module._extensions..js (module.js:432:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/Users/Kainoa/DevLeague/kanakaHacks_Software/KanakaMusicR/kanakamusicR_A/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:136:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
    at require (module.js:385:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/Kainoa/DevLeague/kanakaHacks_Software/KanakaMusicR/kanakamusicR_A/node_modules/enzyme/build/index.js:15:21)
    at Module._compile (module.js:425:26)
    at Module._extensions..js (module.js:432:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/Users/Kainoa/DevLeague/kanakaHacks_Software/KanakaMusicR/kanakamusicR_A/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:136:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
    at require (module.js:385:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (AddNewSong.spec.js:5:28)
    at Module._compile (module.js:425:26)
    at loader (/Users/Kainoa/DevLeague/kanakaHacks_Software/KanakaMusicR/kanakamusicR_A/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:128:5)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/Users/Kainoa/DevLeague/kanakaHacks_Software/KanakaMusicR/kanakamusicR_A/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:138:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
    at require (module.js:385:17)
    at /Users/Kainoa/DevLeague/kanakaHacks_Software/KanakaMusicR/kanakamusicR_A/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:219:27
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Mocha.loadFiles (/Users/Kainoa/DevLeague/kanakaHacks_Software/KanakaMusicR/kanakamusicR_A/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:216:14)
    at Mocha.run (/Users/Kainoa/DevLeague/kanakaHacks_Software/KanakaMusicR/kanakamusicR_A/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:468:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/Kainoa/DevLeague/kanakaHacks_Software/KanakaMusicR/kanakamusicR_A/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha:403:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:425:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:432:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:457:10)
    at startup (node.js:136:18)
    at node.js:972:3
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

this is the package.json

```
{
  "name": "KMR",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js",
    "build": "webpack",
    "watch": "webpack --watch",
    "test": "mocha --require test/helpers/setup.js",
    "lint": "eslint --ignore-path .gitignore --cache ./",
    "cover": "nyc --reporter=lcov --reporter=text --reporter=html --require babel-register --extension .jsx npm test"
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "0.9.1",
    "bluebird": "^3.4.6",
    "errorhandler": "^1.4.3",
    "express": "4.13.4",
    "express-favicon": "^2.0.0",
    "express-jwt": "^5.1.0",
    "lodash": "4.6.1",
    "method-override": "^2.3.6",
    "mysql": "^2.11.1",
    "node-ensure": "0.0.0",
    "pg": "^6.1.0",
    "pg-hstore": "^2.3.2",
    "pg-promise": "^5.3.4",
    "react": "0.14.7",
    "react-dom": "0.14.7",
    "react-modal": "^1.5.2",
    "react-redux": "4.4.0",
    "react-responsive": "^1.2.5",
    "react-router": "2.0.0",
    "redux": "3.3.1",
    "sequelize": "^2.1.3",
    "sequelize-cli": "^2.4.0",
    "sqlite3": "^3.1.6",
    "webpack": "^1.13.2",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.8.4",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.13.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "6.5.2",
    "babel-loader": "6.2.2",
    "babel-polyfill": "6.7.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "6.5.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "6.5.0",
    "babel-register": "6.5.2",
    "chai": "3.5.0",
    "enzyme": "2.0.0",
    "eslint": "2.2.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "5.1.0",
    "eslint-config-standard-jsx": "1.1.1",
    "eslint-config-standard-react": "2.3.0",
    "eslint-loader": "1.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "1.0.8",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "4.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "1.3.2",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-connect": "^5.0.0",
    "gulp-sass": "^2.3.2",
    "jsdom": "8.0.4",
    "json-loader": "0.5.4",
    "livereload": "^0.6.0",
    "mocha": "2.4.5",
    "nyc": "6.0.0",
    "react": "^0.14.7",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "^15.4.1",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.7",
    "sinon": "^1.17.3",
    "supertest": "^2.0.1",
    "webpack": "1.13.2"
  },
  "directories": {
    "test": "test"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "react",
    "workshop",
    "intro",
    "redux"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Show your `package.json` file

Comment: package.json added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a work around for this from [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/8314#issuecomment-261500305)

> make sure that your app contains follow dependencies all in the same
> version in package.json
>
> **react-addons-test-utils**
>
> **react**
>
> **react-dom**

```
"react": "^0.14.7",
"react-addons-test-utils": "^0.14.7",
"react-dom": "^0.14.7",
```

or upgrade to latest versions of above dependencies

Comment: yeah i tried to uninstall and reinstall, all three, but i still get the same results, but now it's telling me react and react-dom have UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY

Comment: Check three for compatibility and upgrade to latest compatible versions

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who has run into this problem lately, note that `react-addons-test-utils` have been **deprecated** and all the test methods have been moved into `react-dom`.
So the fix looks like:
- Remove `react-addons-test-utils` from `package.json` and run `npm update`.
- Change the import statements to reflect the updates. For example:

```js
import { renderIntoDocument } from 'react-dom/test-utils';
```

instead of the old

```js
 import { renderIntoDocument } from 'react-addons-test-utils';
```